# Tortoise SVN not checking for conflicts?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm coming from a git background and just started tinkering with Tortoise SVN. I've been working with one other partner on a small web project and we are able to update files and commit, but when updating and committing a file it won't show any conflict warnings and I never see the yellow icon on any of the files. It will simply overwrite the existing file in the repo. It also fails to show conflicts when updating a file I've been worked on.

I know this usually means there weren't any problems, but I'm pretty sure it's overwriting my working copy rather than merging. I'm using Windows 10 and the latest version of Tortoise (1.9.5) and there were a few issues with the little file icons not showing that I had to fix so maybe this is another OS compatibility issue?

The only other thing is, we were too lazy to use the proper tree/branch structure and we just have a single repo folder we both work from (terrible idea, I know). So instead of merging branches were just updating/committing as we finish things. However, I thought the conflict checking should still be working.

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tortoise SVN can and does check for merge errors. The easiest way to address this in your situation would be utilizing the test merge feature.
Test Merge Option:
[image]

This will lead to a helpful screen, giving you a preview of any potential or certain conflicts detected:

Conflict Preview:
[image]